# Uniform Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+x)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Does the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+x)^2}$$ converge uniformly for $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I mean it doesn't even make sense when $x \in \mathbb{Z}^-$

Comment: Oops, let's say x is positive.

Comment: Then $\sum_{n \ge N} \frac{1}{(n+x)^2} \le \sum_{n \ge N} \frac{1}{n^2}$ which goes to $0$ as $N \to \infty$. So of course you have uniform convergence

Comment: define $\psi(x)=\Gamma'(x)/\Gamma(x)$. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+x)^2} = \psi'(1+x)$. $\psi'(1+x)$ is uniformly convergent for $x>0$.

Comment: You can still ask about convergence for negative x, just don't start the sum at n = 1. The problem is a bit more interesting, imo. Still can deal with all cases with the integral test.

Comment: It is UC on all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Z^-}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in \mathbb{R}$, and $x > 0$. Note that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+x)^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$
Since $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2} \to 0$$
Then by the Weierstrass M-test
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+x)^2}$ is uniformly convergent.